# Gear "--" on automatic Peugeot 207 CC

Tags: automatic-transmission, peugeot, peugeot-207

My partner recently had some issues with her automatic gearbox. When the engine first starts it briefly shows gear "--" before "P ". It may well have always done this but she's a bit worried because it was exhibiting the same behaviour when in gear (whilst all of her transmission fluid was leaking out.) I'm pretty confident that this is normal behaviour but please could someone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens as part of the initialization or checking process for the dash lights & gauges then it sounds fine.

Was the fluid leaking issue corrected? If so, and it behaves correctly when driving then it should be ok, if not then the leak needs correcting.

Comment: It was corrected,  the garage used the wrong seal!